# Logs not saving in File

Tags: spring-boot, log4j

Logs are not saving in the file but are getting displayed on the console. Following is the log4j properties:

```
name=PropertiesConfig
property.filename = logs
appenders = console, file

appender.console.type = Console
appender.console.name = STDOUT
appender.console.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.console.layout.pattern = [%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

appender.file.type = File
appender.file.name = LOGFILE
appender.file.fileName=${filename}/propertieslogs.log
appender.file.layout.type=PatternLayout
appender.file.layout.pattern=[%-5level] %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %c{1} - %msg%n

loggers=file
logger.file.name=transfer
logger.file.level = debug
logger.file.appenderRefs = file
logger.file.appenderRef.file.ref = LOGFILE

rootLogger.level = debug
rootLogger.appenderRefs = stdout
rootLogger.appenderRef.stdout.ref = STDOUT

logger.file.additivity=false
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see a lot of unnecessary fields. Add the below in the .properties file and it should work(Change the values as per you requirement).

```
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, stdout, R, DEBUG
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=ERROR
log4j.logger.org.apache.http.wire=ERROR

#Logging to stdout to catalina.out
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern={"@timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}", "type":"lh_idm", "@message": "%m", "@fields": {"priority": "%p", "logger_name": "%c"}}%n


log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.maxFileSize=20MB
log4j.appender.R.maxBackupIndex=5
log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern={"@timestamp": "%d{yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ}", "type":"lh_idm", "@message": "%m", "@fields": {"priority": "%p", "logger_name": "%c"}}%n
log4j.appender.R.File=${catalina.base}/logs/idme.log
```

Comment: Can u post ur new log4j.properties again.

Comment: I fixed it by putting the log4j.xml file

Comment: Its not a solution, still can u post the xml?